# ruby で無限に sleep させたい

Tags: ruby

ruby で無限に sleep させるには、どう実装するのが一番効率よいですか？

```
sleep INFINITY
```

は、 `Inf out of Time range` のエラーが発生してしまいます。

#### 背景

特定のバッチ(デーモン)は、特定の設定下では何もしない、を実現したいと思っていて、無限に sleep する方法は何があるのか、どう実装するのが一番効率良いのか、と疑問に思い、質問しています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

仕様文書にはパラメータを指定しなければ永久にsleepすると書いてあるようですが。

[Ruby 2.6.0 リファレンスマニュアル > ライブラリ一覧 > 組み込みライブラリ > Kernelモジュール > sleep](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Kernel/m/sleep.html)

> sleep -> Integer
>   sleep(sec) -> Integer
>   　　sec 秒だけプログラムの実行を停止します。
>   　　sec が省略された場合、他スレッドからの Thread#run などで明示的に起こさない限り
>   　　永久にスリープします。Thread#runを呼ぶとその時点で sleepの実行が中断されます。
>   　　
>   　　[PARAM] sec:
>   　　　　停止する秒数を非負の数値で指定します。浮動小数点数も指定できます。 
>   　　　　省略された場合、永久にスリープします。
>   　　[RETURN]
>   　　　　実際に停止していた秒数 (整数に丸められた値) です。